# как менять размер массива динамически

Tags: java, массивы

Есть компонент Spiner, для выпадающего списка нужен массив String[ ]. 
Массив и размер постоянно меняется в процессе работы приложения.
Как динамически менять массив и размер?

```
String[] my_name;
my_name = new String[15];
for (int i=0; i<15;i++) {my_name[i] = "name "+i}
```

Например надо поменять на:

```
my_name = new String[7];
for (int i=0; i<7;i++) {my_name[i] = "change_name "+i}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Массивы - неизменяемые обекты. Если нужно вствлять/удалять объекты из чего либо - используй интерфейс Collection и его наследников. Можно начать с класса ArrayList. [жми и учись. тут примеры](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

Comment: вот блин. действительно, массивы же не могут менять размер, че то я ступил конкретно. Благодарю!.